# Asynchronous export to PDF from org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is it possible to configure `org-mode` to export to PDF in and asynchronous way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried the async dispatch option?

```
C-c C-e C-a
```

toggles the async export.

Comment: Upps, I hadn't niteced that! Thank you.